# Vuex: Computed Property Returns Undefined - asyc Axios

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, axios, vuex

I have async axios calls to my DB that I am dispatching with an action when the site loads.
(I've tried dispatching in beforeEnter() on my Vue-router, beforeCreated(), and Created() on my Form.Vue)

I have a computed property return the info using a getter.

The problem I am experiencing is the data is getting there after the page has finished loading and returns Undefined - nothing renders on the page.

If I check my Vue DevTools, all the data is in the correct places in the State.

How can I get the data to finish loading before the page?

//ACTIONS

```
async loadInputs({ state, getters, commit, dispatch }) {    
 if (!state.loading) {
  commit('setLoading', true)

  const inputLists = axios.get('/companyInputLists')
  const inputs = axios.get('/companyInputs')

  commit('setLoading', false)
  commit('loadInputs' , [await inputLists, await inputs])

 }
},

set ({commit}, value) {
  commit('updateValue', value)
},
```

//MUTATORS

```
setLoading(state, value) {
  state.loading = value
},

 loadInputs(state, data){
  state.layout = {}
  state.data = {}
  data[0].data.map(list => {
    list['inputs'] = []
    state.layout[list.order] = list

    data[1].data.map(input => {
        if(input.list_id == list.id){
            state.layout[list.order].inputs.push(input)
            state.data[input.label] = ''
        }
     })
   })
 },

updateValue(state, value) {
  state.data[value.type] = value.value
},
```

//GETTERS

```
get(state) {
    console.log(state)
    return state
 },
}
```

//FORM.VUE

```
  <span>

    //LIST TEST and v-if test
    <div v-if="lists">
      {{lists}}
    </div>
    test
    {{ lists }}



<v-layout row wrap justify-center>

  <draggable class="dragArea layout row wrap justify-center" :options="{group:'lists'}">
    <v-flex v-for="list in lists" v-bind:key="list.index" :class="[list.label, flexBoxSize(list.size)]">

      <v-subheader v-text="list.label"></v-subheader>

      <draggable class="dragArea layout row wrap" :options="{group:'inputs'}">
        <v-flex v-for="item in list.inputs" v-bind:key="item.index" :class="[item.label, flexBoxSize(item.size)]">

          <textfield v-if="item.type_id == 1" formType="clientForm" :label="item.label" :required="item.required"></textfield>
          <email v-if="item.type_id == 2" formType="clientForm" :label="item.label"  :required="item.required"></email>
          <phone v-if="item.type_id == 3" formType="clientForm" :label="item.label"  :required="item.required"></phone>
          <calendar v-if="item.type_id == 4" formType="clientForm" :label="item.label"  :required="item.required"></calendar>
          <googleMap v-if="item.type_id == 5" formType="clientForm" :label="item.label"  :required="item.required"></googleMap>
          <autocomplete v-if="item.type_id == 6" formType="clientForm" :label="item.label"  :required="item.required"></autocomplete>


        </v-flex>
      </draggable>

    </v-flex>
  </draggable>


  <v-layout row wrap justify-center>
    <submitButton formType="clientForm" path="/clientForm" :references="this.$refs"></submitButton>
    <clearButton formType="clientForm" :references="this.$refs"></clearButton>
  </v-layout>

  </v-layout>
 </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    draggable,
  },

  beforeCreate(){
    this.$store.dispatch('clientForm/loadInputs')
  },

  computed: {
    lists: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters['clientForm/get'].layout
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('clientForm/updateInputList', value)
      }
    }
  },
```

[Vuex Dev Tools Showing Data in State After Page Loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ6A7.png)

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `list['inputs'] = []` in `loadInputs` mutator?

Comment: creates an array in the object to push inputs to

     '''''''''''''''  state.layout[list.order].inputs.push(input)

Comment: Ok. And can you add getters definition to answer?

Comment: Okay, I added the getter

Comment: This line`return this.$store.getters['clientForm/get'].layout` really works?

Comment: Yes. You can test it by adding the data to the store manually so its there before the page loads; the page renders if you do that

Comment: And where you have defined this `clientForm/get` getter?

Comment: clientForm is defined in store.js as a module

`export const store = new Vuex.Store({ 
 modules: {
  clientForm: {
   namespaced: true,

   mutations: clientForm.mutations,
   actions: clientForm.actions,
   state: clientForm.state,
   getters: clientForm.getters,
  }
 }
});`

Comment: Aha, you are using modules :) Now it makes sense :)

Comment: If I console log `this.$store.getters` it returns
`clientForm/get : Object`

Comment: In test: `<div v-if="lists">{{lists}}</div>` <- this show nothing, as the `lists` is an Object.

Comment: shouldn't it just print the object to the screen?
`<div v-if="lists !== undefined" v-model="lists">test</div>`  shows nothing but `<div v-if="lists == undefined" v-model="lists">test</div>` shows test

Comment: No, you cant print whole objects. And you are also using the getters in strange way. The `lists` is undefined due this line `return this.$store.getters['clientForm/get'].layout` for sure.

Comment: you can absolutely print a whole object. I'm doing it right now by manually adding and object to the state. That line of code is fine and returns from the module.

Comment: Try console.dir(this.$store.getters) and and upload to imgur an screenshot of this object.

Comment: i already did that - read comment above.

https://imgur.com/PiXUrQi

Comment: Yes, but I need to see this object properties on screenshot. As in your screenshot of State object.

Comment: https://imgur.com/iqO1CkE - just getters and no ['clientForm/get'].layout shows the data!! yay - getting somewhere!! lol

Comment: Just click on `clientForm/get` property to show its content.

Comment: Try created method as in answer, instead of beforeCreate.

Comment: no errors but created method shows nothing :( 
Strange that returning getters shows the data but getters[clientForm/get] shows undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer over the winter holidays last year and realized there never was a definitive conclusion posted here. After much trial and error and reading through documentation I came across the answer in the Vue.js documentation.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Vue.set(target, key, value)
Adds a property to a reactive object, ensuring the new property is also reactive, so triggers view updates. This must be used to add new properties to reactive objects, as Vue cannot detect normal property additions (e.g. this.myObject.newProperty = 'hi').

Using this function, I was able to load my data via an axios call and have Vue detect the changes and update the DOM.

Also you may want to take note of Vue.delete for removing data with reactivity.

Comment: It's been a while, but would you happen to remember more details of where you placed the Vue.set() statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your `loadInputs` action:

```
async loadInputs ({commit, state}) {
  if (!state.loading) {
    commit('setLoading', true)

    const inputLists = axios.get('/companyInputLists')
    const inputs = axios.get('/companyInputs')

    commit('setLoading', false)
    commit('loadInputs' , [await inputLists, await inputs])
   }
}
```

Component:

```
export default {
  components: {
    draggable,
  },
  computed: {
    lists: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters['clientForm/get'].layout
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('clientForm/updateInputList', value)
      }
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('clientForm/loadInputs')
  },
}
```

Comment: This results in Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: inputLists is not defined

Comment: No. You just forgot rewrite the constats names. Try it again.

Comment: yup that was it. I missed that too haha